# contents get combined in sfcard syncfusion blazor

Tags: html, css, syncfusion

Added flex-wrap:nowrap to header in css , no change get reflected.
[image of card using sfcard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcdtE.png)

Title , subtitle and add to cart to be in correct format without overriding

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Find the below code snippet which includes the SfCard control with header title and subtitle along with proper styles and alignments for your reference.

**Code snippet:**

```
<SfCard ID="HugeImage">
    <CardImage Image="https://blazor.syncfusion.com/demos/_content/BlazorServerCommon_NET7/images/cards/steven.png" />
    <CardHeader Title="Harrisburg Keith" SubTitle="@CardSubTitle" />
    <CardContent Content="Hi, I'm a creative graphic designer for print and new media based in Edenbridge." />
    <CardFooter>
       <CardFooterContent>
       <SfButton CssClass="e-btn e-outline e-primary">Follow me</SfButton>
       </CardFooterContent>
    </CardFooter>
</SfCard>

 @code{
     public string CardSubTitle = "@harrisburg_keith";
}
 <style>
    .e-card .e-card-header .e-card-header-caption .e-card-sub-title {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    .e-card .e-card-header .e-card-header-caption .e-card-header-title {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .e-card .e-card-content {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    #HugeImage {
        text-align: center
    }
        #HugeImage > .e-card-image {
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 64px;
            height: 64px;
            min-height: 64px;
        }
      
</style>
```

Refer to the below documentation for more information,

**Documentation**: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/card/header-content